# Monaco editor won't show in a react app

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, editor, monaco-editor

I started using react-monaco-editor library because I want to add a cool json editor in my web react application.

I followed the instruction on github: [react-monaco-editor-DOC](https://github.com/superRaytin/react-monaco-editor)

but it seems like I am missing something which is probably not shared in the DOC for the webpack setup. After I used the webpack setup instructions from the doc, import the library and added the lines:

```js
import MonacoEditor from 'react-monaco-editor';

class Editor extends React.Component{

  editorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
    console.log('editorDidMount', editor);
    editor.focus();
  }

  render(){ 
    const options = {
      selectOnLineNumbers: true
    };

    return(
      <div>
        <MonacoEditor
         width="800"
         height="600"
         language="json"
         value="// some code"
         options={options}
         editorDidMount={this.editorDidMount}/>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

I get an empty text area.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue. The solution was to configure Webpack to copy a `vs` folder from inside an npm module or to use a `require.config`. Another way is to put it into a public folder manually. I'm not sure whether it's the correct way, but in my case this workaround works just perfect.

Comment: Should I set any additional settings in webpack config? CopyWebpackPlugin doesn't help me. I have an error context.require is not a function

Comment: It seems that now the `react-monaco-editor` doesn't need any special webpack config. At least with CRA it just works out of the box after installing via `npm`.

Comment: @AndrewTatomyr does it work with error highlighting as well? I found that it works for the most part but I still can't get error highlighting and i'm trying to add the webpack plugin

Comment: @AKrush95 to be honest, I do not quite remember. Please check out discussion here:  “Short guide to using Monaco with Create React App” by Henrik Haugbølle https://link.medium.com/VgN0DcoMOX

Comment: And also you can check the working example with highlighting enabled: https://github.com/tatomyr/estimate-it

Answer (score 1):

here is my sample of require part:

```
render() {
  const requireConfig = {
    url: 'node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js',
    paths: {
      vs: 'node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs'
    }
  };

  return (
    <MonacoEditor
      ...
      requireConfig={requireConfig}
    />
  );
}
```